# Webservices in Websphere portal server

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere, websphere-portal, soapheader

I am trying to call a webservice from Websphere Portal server, however I Notice a very strange behavior with the SOAP message.

In the request msg that I send, there are no headers present, whereas in the request received by the producer, additional headers are added like date timezone locale and stuff like that. This was initially causing a few problems but latter the producer managed to bypass the headers so all is good now.But I am just curious to know why they are added in portal and can be disabled.

I am using JAX RPC,

This is the message that I get when I print it at my end before sending the request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
```

This is the message that is received at the producers end.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <InternationalizationContext soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/webservices/InternationalizationContext">
        <Locales xmlns="">
            <Locale>
                <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
                <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            </Locale>
            <Locale>
                <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
            </Locale>
        </Locales>
        <TimeZoneId xmlns="">GMT</TimeZoneId>
    </InternationalizationContext>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
```

Regards
Snehan Solomon

Comment: Can you show an example of these additional headers? You should also mention which Web service API you are using (JAX-RPC, JAX-WS, third party?).

Comment: Andreas, 
I have updated the question with the details you had requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This header is generated by the [internationalization service](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/i18n/concepts/cin_intserv.html) in WebSphere. It is possible to disable that service entirely, but maybe Portal server requires it. It is likely that there is also a way to disable the propagation of the internationalization context for a given JAX-RPC request, but I didn't find any documentation.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for helping me figure this out, I believe this feature is by default enabled in WPS, would you happen to know if this could be disabled for individual WS clients?